# Difficulties with std::greater<int>() comparator with partial_copy_sort, "no matching function call.." on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, sorting

Currently working with some ol' C++, but am having a touch of trouble with using the `greater<int>()` comparator for finding the **top k** keys with the max value in a map.

When compiling receiving the error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:5138:17: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::__1::greater<int>'
        if (__comp(*__first, *__result_first))
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:5160:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__partial_sort_copy<std::__1::greater<int> &, std::__1::__hash_map_iterator<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >, int>, void *> *> >, std::__1::__wrap_iter<std::__1::pair<std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >, int> *> >' requested here
        return __partial_sort_copy<_Comp_ref>(__first, __last, __result_first, __result_last, __comp);
       ^
```

Yikes that's ugly... Here's some context:

### Context

I have an `unordered_map<vector<string>,int>>` construct which I am attempting to find the top **k** strings in my map which have the max `int` value.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
//...
unordered_map<vector<string>, int> database;
vector<pair <vector<string>, int> > top_k(3);
partial_sort_copy(my_map.begin(),
                  my_map.end(),
                  top_k.begin(),
                  top_k.end(), 
                  greater<int>());
```

Not the best cpp programmer, would love to hear some suggestions you had to remedy this situation?

Comment: don't tag C without reason, C and C++ are different language.

Comment: The code you posted is a syntax error, and if I try to "fix" it, I get a completely different error.

Comment: @melpomene, the "*" were posted to emphasize, but I can remove them if this is what you are referring to.

Comment: The next problems are: `unordered_map` is undeclared; `vector` is undeclared.

Comment: Ah yes of course, thanks for pointing that out! I'll put them into the question, as I have included them on my end, but forgot to add them above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on cppreference, the comparator function requires a type signature like so:

> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
>
> The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that an object of type RandomIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them. ​

The `RandomIt` iterators correspond to the `top_k` structure which when dereferenced has type `pair <vector<string>, int>`, while `std::greater<int>` has comparison function of `bool operator()( const int& lhs, const int& rhs )`. In other words, this does not work because `pair <vector<string>, int>` does not convert to `int`.

One solution is to provide your own comparator:

```
std::partial_sort_copy(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), top_k.begin(), top_k.end(),
[](const pair<vector<string>, int>& lhs, const pair<vector<string>, int>& rhs) {
    return lhs.second > rhs.second;
});
```